# Adding dynamic rows to the mail content

Tags: php, email

```
$content="<table width='200' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>product name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

The above table is the content of the mail.

`$pdtname , $price and $qty` contains productname, product price and product quantity.

```
$msgSent=@mail("aaa@gmail.com",$sub,$content,$headers);
```

If the user select one or more products

Is it possible to multiply the second row of the table inside the `$content` according to the number of products selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$content = "<table width='200' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>product name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
  </tr>";
foreach($products as $product){
  $content .= "  <tr>
    <td>".$product['name']."</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>";
}
$content .= "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop like this

```
$content = "<table width='200' border='0'>
<tr>
    <td>product name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
</tr>";
foreach($rows as $row){
    $content .= "  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['product_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['product_price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['product_quantity'];?></td>
  </tr>";
}  
$content .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Ofcourse It will add product name,price,quantity also...right..??

Comment: Can anyone tell me the better ans that listed here..??